# arrowDB - is there a way to move development data to production?

Tags: appcelerator, arrowdb

I've built an app using arrowDB for the backend. Is there a simple way to duplicate development data to production?

Seems like an oversight not to be able to do this, have an app going through review process and just realised all our test data won't be accessible

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no feature like this right now.

You could probably build your own using their [REST API](https://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/guide/rest).  I haven't seen a solution like this built yet but I definitely think it is possible.  If I get some free time, I will try to put one together and will post a link here.

Comment: I'm thinking the same myself - having to hack things a bit by changing the production keys to match development keys as my app got rejected twice as there was no data in the production app Apple were testing and I was tearing my hair out trying to work out why. Third time lucky I hope...